# Can App Script triggers stick when making copies of file?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a trigger on a Google Sheet set up to run a function weekly. I am hoping to scale this trigger out to my team without having to go into each teammate's individual sheet's script editor and enable it. Do you know if triggers can stick when making a copy of a master sheet that has a trigger set up? Can triggers be saved and used via shared libraries? I haven't had much success and would love some pointers if you have them.

Thanks!

Comment: No `````````````````​`````````````````

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the answer is no. Only the owner of the google account can create triggers for himself/herself.
However, there is a great alternative. You can add this code to the master file (script editor):

```
function createTrigger() {

      ScriptApp.newTrigger("Name_Of_The_Function_You_Want_To_Trigger")
               .timeBased().onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.MONDAY)
               .atHour(7).create();
   
}
```

and when the person of your team executes this function (in his own copy of the master file), the script will create for him a particular trigger for:

- Function: "Name_Of_The_Function_You_Want_To_Trigger"
- type: timeBased()
- Hour: 7am
- When: weekly, every Monday

That saves you a lot of time, since the user (your colleague) has to run this particular function just once from his own file.

Comment: Thanks Marios! So sorry for the delay on this -- so just to be clear, because the time driven one (or even on form submit for example) are installable triggers, the user will need to actually run the function for it the trigger to be created? Would using an onOpen function to create a trigger be a workaround? Or does the user still need to authorize?